# Trying to update skype in terminal and message pops up. So can't run sudo apt-get update or anything unless i fix that

Tags: 12.04

```
E.malformed line 56 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse) 
E. The list o sources could not be read
```

My version is 12.04lts

Comment: It seems as though your source list is messed up. Did you modify it at all?

Comment: well what does line 56 in your sources say?

Comment: well i dont remember modifying anything in that line, just trying to install

Comment: I also can't open the software centre, whenever i try, it just can't load